# What's the meaning of $ sign in java language?

Tags: java

Recently I'm reading an API document,I always see people use '$' sign like this:

```
Object result = barService.$invoke("sayHello", new String[] { "java.lang.String" }, new Object[] { "World" });
```

I've searched a long time,still can't get the meaning of this sign.Could anybody tell me how to use '$' and what does it represent for?

Comment: Afaik it doesn't have a special meaning on a language level, i.e. you are free to use it in method names, e.g. `void $tupidMethod();`. Thus at that level the meaning is up to the developers of that api.

Comment: Java language specification says: The dollar sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems. Otherwise, no special meaning.